# How to Insert values into database and check

Tags: android, database

In my Application I have 2 EditText and Button.

On button click i want to get values from EditText and insert it into SQLite Databse

But my code does not work , and my database does not create.

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText1,editText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editText1.getText().toString();
            String family = editText2.getText().toString();

        }
    });

}
```

And Person.java :

```
public class Person {

private long id;
private String name;
private String family;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String name, String family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

public Person(long id, String name, String family) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFamily() {
    return family;
}

public void setFamily(String family) {
    this.family = family;
}
```

And PersonDatabaseAdapter :

```
public class PersonDatabaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper;

public PersonDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    sqLiteOpenHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "database.db", null, 1) {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String sql = "create table tbl_persons (id integer primary key, name text, family text)";
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        }
    };
}

public long savePerson(Person person) {
    String name = person.getName();
    String family = person.getFamily();
    long id = -1;

    SQLiteDatabase database = null;

    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("family", family);

        database = sqLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        id = database.insert("tbl_persons", null, values);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Database", "Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if( database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            database.close();
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any of exceptions in your logcat ?

Comment: If there is the real code, there are some points need to be considered 1)where is the call for savePerson() method?
2)In on click method you are getting name and family locally they are not being utilized any where?

Comment: i have a question about above codes,Do I have to bring it up here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `savePerson` function in your `onClick` method.

```
findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String name = editText1.getText().toString();
        String family = editText2.getText().toString();
        Person person = new Person(name, family);
        savePerson(person);
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. What does it say exactly?

Comment: When i use savePerson(person); It turns red and say Cannot resolve method 'savePerson (com.packagedomain.home.packagename.Person)

Comment: You need to define the `savePerson` function inside `MainActivity`